# Is it possible to remove a single line of css from a plugin file on a Wordpress site?

Tags: php, css, function

The page builder I'm using has just had an update and they've changed the way the builder works. This has broken a lot of my layouts on tablet and mobile browser widths.

I have found the offending line of code, and I'm wondering if it's possible to remove this somehow through my functions folder? I have had a look and I found out that it's possible to dequeue whole stylesheets from plugins, but I only want to get rid of that one line of code.

Some background info on the problem – My page builder allows you to enter a row width which is then added to the row as a `max-width` value. However, when the browser reaches a width below 980px, the width value entered into the builder is overwritten by the following line of code:

```
.et_divi_builder #et_builder_outer_content .et_pb_section .et_pb_row,
.et_divi_builder #et_builder_outer_content .et_pb_section.et_section_specialty .et_pb_row {
    max-width: 1080px !important;
}
```

This is extremely annoying and has led me to have to attempt to rebuild several of my pages, none of which I can rebuild to the same standard with this holding me back. I can't overwrite this in my own `style.css` file, as the only ways of doing so are by giving the max-width property a value of `none` or `initial`, both of which overwrite the width value I added into the builder in the first place.

I've located the plugin file containing the code and if I comment it out or delete it, the builder works fine as before. The trouble is, whenever the plugin updates it'll come back and I'll have to update it via the back door every single time.

Is there a way of removing just this line?

Comment: Instead of removing it, override it to what you want it to be. As long as your rule is equally (or more) specific and comes after this one in the page's HTML, it'll take precedence. (You'll need yours to be `!important`, too.)

Comment: Are you using a child theme? I thought they existed so situations like this didn't happen.

Comment: @ceejayoz I can't override it – all width values are variable and depend on the row and how wide you want it to be. Each row width is configured in the builder settings by a slider that goes from 10% to 100%. At 980px, this is overridden by the CSS rule I mentioned in my question. Overriding this myself is impossible unless I add a class to every row and then give it a set value in my stylesheet (i.e 85%, 90% etc), which defeats the object of having a page builder plugin. Is it possible to remove this CSS rule?

Comment: @j08691 – No I'm not, it's a very basic and stripped back theme I built myself. When I started using Wordpress I was a complete novice and for some reason I thought this was a better option to using a pre-built theme.